# Retaining punctuations in a word

Tags: regex, python-3.x

How can i remove punctuations from a line, but retain punctuation in the word using ***re*** ??

For Example :

```
Input = "Hello!!!, i don't like to 'some String' .... isn't"
Output = (['hello','i', 'don't','like','to', 'some', 'string', 'isn't'])
```

I am trying to do this:

```
re.sub('\W+', ' ', myLine.lower()).split()
```

But this is splitting the words like "***don't***" into ***don*** and ***t***.

Comment: Search for either space+' or '+space instead of \W.

Comment: @JulienD : Thanks for the quick reply!!I am kind of new to Python and RegEx!!So i din't understand what you meant!!Did you mean something like this "re.sub(' +', '  ', myLine.lower()).split())"

Comment: Split and strip off the punctuation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lookarounds in your regex:

```
>>> input = "Hello!!!, i didn''''t don't like to 'some String' .... isn't"
>>> regex = r'\W+(?!\S*[a-z])|(?<!\S)\W+'
>>> print re.sub(regex, '', input, 0, re.IGNORECASE).split()
['Hello', 'i', "didn''''t", "don't", 'like', 'to', 'some', 'String', "isn't"]
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qiNd4L/5)

`\W+(?!\S*[a-z])|(?<!\S)\W+` matches a non-word, non-space character that doesn't have a letter at previous position or a letter at next position after 1 or more non-space characters.

Comment: worked like a charm!!Thank you!!Is this the best way we can do this??Or do we have more optimal ways??(P.S : Just want to learn more, there's nothing wrong with the suggested method)

Comment: I think lookarounds is the only possible way to do it using regex.

Comment: For the above answer : "din't" comes out as "din't", but " din'''''''''''t " comes out as "dint". How can i solve this issue? I have been trying this since yesterday, but couldn't succeed!!Any suggestions on how i can change the regex?

Comment: Try this regex `(?<![a-z])[^\w\s]+|[^\w\s]+(?!\S*[a-z])`

Comment: Yes!!the way i have framed question seems confusing!!Sorry about that!!I want the regex to just retain the punctuations(symbols) inside a word, otherwise i want it to remove every punctuation that appears in the String!!So in your example,     Hello!!!!    has symbols after the word, thus the symbols should be removed!!Whereas     Hell!!!!!o    has symbols inside the word, and therefore they should be retained.

Comment: I tried the same regex that you suggested now, but that removes all the continuous symbols inside the word and replaces them by a single symbol: `Hell!!!!!!!!o` becomes `Hell!o`

Comment: Try this regex `\W+(?!\S*[a-z])|(?<!\S)\W+`

Comment: This works!!awesome!!It would be great if you could just explain the regex!!I am kind of getting confused!!

Comment: i tried the regex for the expression    `Hello!!!, i don''''''t li_ke t_____o '''''   'some String' .... isn't`    , i got    `Hello i don''''''t li_ke t_____osome String isn't`   , where as the expected output is     `Hello i don''''''t li_ke t_____o some String isn't `, i.e. `t_____o` some is recognized as one word!! So i can work on the regex to modify it based on my need, but since i din't understand your regex, i am finding it hard to modify it!!

Comment: `\W+(?!\S*[a-z])` means match 1 or more of non-word characters that is not followed by `non-space-chars+letter`. `(?<!\S)\W+` matches 1 or more of non-word characters that is not preceded by a non-space.

Comment: wow!!Awesome!!I guess i can modify the regex now!!Thanks a lot Sir!! You are really an inspiration!I mean it!!